# How to get user's books from Facebook with GraphQL?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I can get a user's likes from Facebook using graphql, but the books and movies a user has **read** and **seen** aren't included. If the user explicitly **likes** a book, then that **is** returned via the API.

The docs suggest I need to request the `user_likes` & `user_actions.books` permissions to get the books, but when I make a request to `me/books` I don't get any `Pages` returned and there are no errors.

I'm using restfb and here's my code:

```
 val connection = facebookClient.fetchConnection("me/books", classOf[Page],
    Parameter.`with`("fields", "id,name,category"))
```

I can't even get my books back by using the graphql explorer (using the request `me/books?fields=name`).

What permissions do I need to use to retrieve books and movies, and what graphql query do I need to issue?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, the endpoint is `me/books.reads`.